# npx create-react-app my-app --typescript ERROR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, react-native

operation not permitted, unlink

...\my-app-ts\node_modules.staging\typescript-3b9492ef\lib\typingsInstaller.js'

25398 verbose node v12.12.0
25399 verbose npm  v6.12.0
25400 error code EPERM
25401 error syscall unlink
25402 error path ...\my-app-ts\node_modules.staging\typescript-
3b9492ef\lib\typingsInstaller.js
25403 error errno -4048
25404 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

25405 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
25405 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or 
antivirus),
25405 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
25405 error
25405 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-
check the
25405 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try 
running
25405 error the command again as root/Administrator.
25406 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]

Comment: Было бы неплохо уточнить что за ОС

Answer (score -1):

Сделайте то же самое от имени администратора
`sudo npx create-react-app my-app --typescript`